# Can you get tag of a folder with box API?

Tags: box-api

Box allows you to create a tag for your folder, but how do you get that info out of the API? I don't see tag returning in the `GET /folders/{id} API`. Tag is not considered as a metadata either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you take a look at the [Fields write up in the documentation](https://box-content.readme.io/reference#fields) it mentions that some fields are not returned by default. Within the docs they are listed in italics in objects, and have to be retrieved by adding a `?fields={field name}` to your request.

The [Folder Object](https://box-content.readme.io/reference#folder-object-1) has a ***tags*** parameter that you can fetch, but it is one of the ones not returned by default.

In this case, the API call would be `GET /folders/{id}?fields=tags`. One thing to note is that it will only return the tags in this case with some basic information (type of object and object id), not the full folder object. If you need other information in the call, you can add it to the fields that you want to pull. For example, if you wish to get the **owned_by** parameter as well, your request would be `GET /folders/{id}?fields=owned_by,tags`